# Providing biased data to analyst -- how could they use information about the bias?

Tags: inference, bias

I'm working on a project that provides an anonymized dataset to a service. Clients of this service will often use our data to make inferences to the population it's drawn from.

Our data is known to be biased with respect to certain categorical variables that (for privacy reasons) can't be included in it. The mismatch between the distribution of such a variable in the population vs our dataset could well be significant for some analysts.

For each variable, we're allowed to provide aggregate information about the representation of different groups in the data and how these differ from the population. But we can't correct the bias or give details about the characteristics of individuals in our data. In particular, we can't (for now) allow the user to take a stratified sample of our data that removes the mismatch.

To my **questions**:

If you were working on an inferential project using our data, what would you want to know? How might you use that information? Is there anything else we could do to make it as easy as possible?

(I appreciate "inferential project" is very vague. I simply don't know which methods analysts will be using in the future but still want to be responsible and transparent about what we're providing. But as a non-data-analyst I'm interested in examples / use cases as well as general observations.)

Comment: This sounds quite tricky, as you don't seem to have any information on *how* or even *if* the variable in question has any effect on what you're studying. Suppose you have biased dataset of 90% men and 10% women and want to apply it to a population that has a 50-50 split. If you want to make inferences about height, you should correct for the sex distribution, but not if you want to make inferences about number of toes. The scenario here seems even more challenging, as we have no data on whether the biased feature is related to the study feature to begin with, much less how to correct for it.

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie That's true -- my assumption is that the analyst will know that the thing they're studying might be affected by the bias, i.e. they know they're studying height and the bias affects that. But the difficulty is that unless they already know the relationship between height and sex, there's probably no way to use our bias information to improve their model...?

Comment: I really think this question is impossible to answer without more specifics. You can liken this to asking a DIY forum about how to negotiate with contractors. At the end of the day, you just need to be able to discuss your concern candidly with the vendor, and they should be capable of providing a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @AdamO The problem is we're producing data for "general consumption" in a wide research community. We have many datasets like this and need an automated process. To pick up your analogy, it's more like "What practices can we adopt to ensure all the contractors working on our multiple building projects are made aware of dangers on-site that may or may not affect them?" I'm looking for good, actionable ways to describe bias. I'm aware it *might* be impossible to do much here but not knowledgeable enough to be sure...

Comment: @helveticat you're missing the forest for the trees metaphorically speaking :) these are issues that are handled by following guidances and SOPs for vendor selection, validation, and alliance. In my past CRO world, these kinds of big contracts are pitched as a "center of excellence". "Quality" means different things to do different people.

Comment: @AdamO Are you suggesting there's *nothing* we can report that would be worthwhile for some users? Not even whether there are distributional discrepancies at all?